# Metro - XAML AppBar ZIndex (need frame to overlay appBar)

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro, z-index, appbar

I am creating a GlobalPage/FrameHoster that will contain my AppBar and then a Frame control which will host all of my application pages.  This all works great except that some of page navigation controls are hidden by the app bar.  How can I display the App Bar but have its ZIndex set to lower than that of my hostFrame?

```
<Page.TopAppBar>
    <AppBar x:Name="globalAppBar" Padding="10,0,10,0" IsSticky="True" IsOpen="True" Background="Transparent" IsHoldingEnabled="True" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" >
         <Grid>
             <banner:AppBannerBar/>
         </Grid>
    </AppBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>

<Grid>
      <Frame x:Name="hostFrame"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The AppBars are system driven and they overlay your entire app. I don't think you'll be able to hide them with controls/popups inside your app.

However, you could just close them when you don't want anything hidden on your screen.